# Testing strategy for SCDF based batch pipelines / flows

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Could you please share any artifacts which talks about testing strategy for SCDF based batch pipelines / flows? It can cover manual as well as automated way of testing.

Comment: Can you provide some more context about your use case or a more specific question?

Comment: We are going to automate business process using spring batch and use SCDF to orchestrate the pipeline and schedule jobs. Would like to understand standard methodology to test these batch jobs created in SCDF? Automated way of functional/integration testing, Performance testing. I hope this clarifies bit more.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was recenlty answered in SCDF's Gitter channel — see [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow?at=5ff0c5b7de608143155ac081](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow?at=5ff0c5b7de608143155ac081)

As far as you're using the TASK Java DSL, you'd be able to programmatically define and launch task/batch-jobs from SCDF. We use this in the product for our end-to-end acceptance tests, as well. The links to the docs and the test-suite are shared in the Gitter thread.